# Can I make this changes to this diagram of a ESP32-CAM?

Tags: esp32, camera

Have a good day! I am kinda new with electronics circuits, and therefore I got some doubts about this diagram of a ESP32-CAM

I want to use a 5V instead of 3.3V. Do i need to add some resistors or capacitors to do so?

If the on-off switch is for turn on/off the device?
the push switch. Its a button that when GPIO13 receaves changes on his signal activate a code (I mean, does it act like a button code activator) If its not how can I put a button so the  ESP32-CAM start /stop filming?

Thank you

[image]

I got the image from this source
http://technoreview85.blogspot.com/2019/08/ESP32spycam.html

Comment: you cannot apply 5 V to a 3.3 V pin

Comment: @jsotola it does have a 5v pin. But  I didn't know if I do so I needed to add some more components

Answer (score 0):

The ESP32-CAM can be powered via the 3.3V or 5V pins. It is safe to apply 5V to the ESP32 Vcc pin. Just make sure that no other ESP32 pin is exposed to a voltage over 3.3V.